black screen after changing resolution in CentOS 9
When I installed CentOS 9 I faced with an error like this: "nouveau sched error 20". I solved it by adding "splash nouveau.modeset=0" to the end of kernel configuration in the grub boot loader. It's OK now. but my problem is that when I change my screen resolution from 3840x2160 to 1920x1080 or any other resolution I face with black screen and just mouse cursor is shown and I have to press escape and back to my default and recommended screen resolution. What is the issue? is it a bug? I want to change my screen resolution to 1920x1080 for lower power usage and better frame rate. My device is Lenovo Y50-70 laptop.
I searched in network but I couldn't find a good solution.
